# How to prerender Vue 2 on server w/ PHP

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, prerender, server-side-rendering

as Vue 2 has been published and it contains SSR feature, i've got following question.

Is it possible to perform a prerender for bots similar to Prerender.io, but with PHP (Laravel) on own server? If it is, could you show me the direction?

Thanks a lot.